# Saving command output to bash-history

Tags: bash

Does anyone know of a way to hack bash to intercept and save output for each command that it executes?

Comment: How about bash | tee bash.out

Comment: It will make your history grows redundant fast.

Comment: This could be interesting for a security course at school.

Comment: I ended up using hacking my .emacs_bash to run script each time I start shell. Seems to grow about 1GB per week which is low enough to keep all history.

Answer (score 1):

you can use GNU `screen` utility ( http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/ ) with `-L` switch

Answer (score 0):

I gave this some thought, and in the simplest form, you have this:

```
$ cat clone 
#! /bin/bash
bash -i |tee >(cat >>/tmp/bash.log.$$)
# $ vim clone 
# Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal

$ ./clone  
$ du -sb /tmp/bash.log.9609 
29  /tmp/bash.log.9609
109 /tmp/bash.log.9609
161 /tmp/bash.log.9609
213 /tmp/bash.log.9609
```

Comment: why the `tee >(cat >>/tmp/bash.log.$$)`? Wouldn't `tee -a /tmp/bash.log.$$` do the same?